# Here i need to prevent from reload my angular component when we are navigating to browser back and forward button

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, angular7, angular-routing

I have **component-A(Details item page)** and **Component-B(selectable list page)**, the scenario is like when I goto **component-A(Details page)** and here I need to add some labels so, I goto **component-B** and select labels and go back to a detail page with selected labels it works fine if I go to **A -> B** component and **B -> A** component using web button. But when I navigate **component-B** again with the browser forward button and then select labels and go back but in this case, when I go back to **component-A(Detail)** at that time it reloads the component so, whatever data I have taken from **component-B** which is lost so, it won't reflect on **component-A**. this thing only happens with the browser back and forward button. in the normal web button navigation works fine.

When I goto component A -> B it will change my route. I have used routerReuseStrategy but somehow due to some blocker, I'm not able to manage my data with that.

I need to stop reloading my detail component.

Version
Angular - 7.2
Ionic - 4.12

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: is your intention to have data retention after navigation?

Comment: No really, when I navigate throw the browser forward navigation button (A -> B) my previous component destroys So when came again (B -> A) my component reinitialize, and my previous component data lose because of this. But when I navigate throw the web button it's working fine here component is not destroyed. So here how can I prevent destroy my component with browser forward navigation? Thanks! @BillCheng